# Redirect perror output to fprintf(stderr, " ")

Tags: c, stderr, errno

In case a system call function fails, we normally use perror to output the error message. I want to use fprintf to output the perror string. How can I do something like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, perror output string here);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
#include <errno.h>

fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Note: strerror doesn't apply `\n` to the end of the message

Comment: Thanks maverik. But the output will be exactly identical to perror string?

Comment: So i am doing something like this: `fprintf(stderr, "LeakTracer: timer_settime failed to set timer (timer_trackStartTime): %s \n",strerror(errno);`

Comment: Not exactly the same. When using perror usually you write: `perror("fopen")`. This results in `"fopen: <error description>"`. In case of `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno))` you should give: `<error_description>`, so if you need exactly the same, use: `fprintf(stderr, "fopen: %s\n", strerror(errno))`. Of course you should replace `fopen` by the name of your function