# How use perror() but output the prompt to a file

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, android-emulator

I know the general usage of the `perror()`.

But right now, I want to export its result into a file, not the console. By the way, i run it in under the android emulator's adb shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483120/redirect-perror-output-to-fprintfstderr/5483164)

Comment: @maverik, but the "problem" is *this* question asks for a "a file", while the other question asks for output to stderr. So the answer happens to be quite similar, but the questions are quite a bit different.

Comment: `fprintf` is able to write to file just like `fputs` used in top-answer here.

Comment: @maverik, yes, I am not talking about the answers, but the wording of the questions, especially the titles.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, may be you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `strerror()` instead:

```
fprintf(logfile, "Something went wrong: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Or, you could redirect `stderr` to a file using `dup2()` and then carry on using `perror()`.

**EDIT**: It was early when I answered this originally and my brain wasn't firing on all cylinders. There is no need to use `sprintf()` followed by `fputs()` as `fprintf()` can do it all (thanks to @maverik).

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the whole `stderr` to that file. Here is a Unix way of doing this:

```
int fd = open("logfile", O_WRONLY); // 'fd' stands for 'file descriptor
close(2); // close stderr
dup(fd); // duplicate fd so that it's copy will be the lowest available value -- 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can direct the stderr to a file of your choosing, e.g $ ./program 2> errlog